# socket.io emit data by android application to node.js server

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I have problem with emiting data by android application to node.js server.

node.js server:

```
var app = require('http').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

 app.listen(1000);

 app.on('connection', function (client) { 

   client.name = client.remoteAddress + ':' + client.remotePort;
   console.log(client.name + ' connected!'); 

    client.on('sensorChanged', function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
});
```

and it's Android application

```
private TextView txtView;
private SocketIO socket;

try {
    socket = new SocketIO("http://localhost:1000");
    socket.connect(this);
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    txtView.setText(e1.getMessage());
}

socket.emit("sensorChanged", "asd");
```

When I start application, server sees my phone, but when I emit event, server dont respond. 
Do you have any idea where is the problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm facing the same one.

Answer (score 0):

i did it like

```
 socket.on("new message", new Emitter.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {

            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) args[0];

            try {//do stuff here}
         catch(Exception){}
 }
}
```

Comment: I guess it's code from android application. I will use it, but right now I need emit data from Android app to node server. I think the problem is in this line:
    socket.emit("sensorChanged", "asd"); 
but it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's code from android application. I will use it, but right now I need emit data from Android app to node server. 
I think the problem is in this line:

```
`socket.emit("sensorChanged", "asd");`
```

but it looks good.

Comment: yup its fine from the android side.

Comment: are you able to ping the server?

Comment: Yes. When I connect to the server, server say: "<user> connected!". So I guess there's no problem with connection between android and server.

Comment: hmm.., so there is issue from server side, no problem from android side

Comment: I tried connect html website with this server and it works. So in my opinion server side is OK. No idea whats going on

Comment: try it ....  change your server address to http://chat.socket.io and replace this socket.emit("new message", "message");

Comment: I dont know what result it should give, but I guess I have to be able see my message on http://chat.socket.io . In this case it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like:

```
    socket = new SocketIO();

    try {
        socket.connect("http://chat.socket.io", this);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    socket.emit("new message", "hello TEST");
```

I dont know what result it should give, but I guess I have to be able see my message on http://chat.socket.io . In this case it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and resolved by adding user.

```
mSocket.emit("add user", "Andhradroid");
```